# How can I change rank of root process from zero to something else, say 15, in a MPI_Reduce routine?

Tags: c, mpi, root, reduce, rank

How can I change rank of root process from zero to something else, say 15, in a MPI_Reduce routine? For example:

```
MPI_Reduce(myvalue,sum,1,MPI_REAL,MPI_SUM,15,new_communicator);
```

I would appreciate if someone could explain this. Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Are you only trying to reduce to another process than zero? That's what the root parameter is for. I think you are under a misapprehension that "root process" is a concept. It's not. There is process zero, and often-but-not-always reduce will go to process zero, and there is "the root of the reduction" which is also usually zero, but is completely independent.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what do you think a root process is?

Comment: Careful here: in your call, you're using `MPI_REAL` which corresponds to a Fortran data type. Considering you're coding in C (well, at least it looks very much like it), you should be using (I assume) either `MPI_FLOAT` or `MPI_DOUBLE`. Also, careful that both `myvalue` and `sum` must be pointers. Could these be `&myvalue` and `&sum`?

Comment: Thank you High Performance Mark and Gilles ! You are right.